# Using custom metric with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I am currently using Tensorflow with dense layers for a binary classification problem (with sigmoïd output for probability).

### Introduction

For the training I have seen that we can use a True Positive metric from tensorflow. Now I want to create my own to still focus on True Positive precision but only on the 11% best prediction.
i.e:
When the algorithm make its prediction, I want to considere the 11% best prediction as true and other ones as False.

So, to sum up, I am trying to define a function that will be use like that:

```py
def customMetric(y_true, y_pred):
   ....

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[customMetric])
```

With other models, if it can helps, I did it like that:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_sorted = sorted(y_pred, reverse=True)
threshold = y_sorted[math.floor(len(y_sorted) * 0.11)]
print(classification_report(y_test, [v >= threshold for v in y_pred], output_dict=False))
```

### Problem

Now after research on internet (and here), I have seen a lot of different approches to do it but I am always stuck with different kind of Error.

I have used:

- tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k=k) {considering k precalculated just for a special training)
- Naïve method such as taking y_pred, trying to sort with tf directly of with .numpy() to convert y_pred
  and a lot of other way but I get each time confused with different error such as float type (then I used cast) or just no possibilty to get shape.

My last try is the following code:

```
def customMetric(y_true, y_pred):
    # Sort the predicted values in descending order
    sorted_indices = tf.argsort(y_pred, direction='DESCENDING')

    # Calculate the number of elements to consider as true
    num_true = tf.cast(tf.math.ceil(0.11 * tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[0], tf.float32)), tf.int32)

    # Get the top 'num_true' indices
    top_indices = tf.cast(sorted_indices[:num_true], tf.float32)
    
    # Create a tensor of ones for the true labels
    true_labels = tf.ones_like(y_true)
    
    # Set the elements at top indices to 1, and the rest to 0
    top_indices = tf.cast(top_indices, dtype=tf.int32)
    true_labels = tf.cast(true_labels, dtype=tf.float32)
    top_indices = tf.reshape(top_indices, (-1, 1))
    true_labels = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(true_labels, top_indices, tf.ones_like(top_indices, dtype=tf.float32))

    # Calculate true positive accuracy
    true_positive = K.sum(K.round(y_true * true_labels))
    true_positive_accuracy = true_positive / K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))

    return true_positive_accuracy
```

This is the only one that gave me the possibility to try it without exception .. But i always get None.

I think this is my limited understanding of Tensorflow (and its tensor) that make me in trouble.

I even sold my soul to the famous ChatGPT but wasn't able to helps.
So, I would like to know if someone here has an idea and could help.
Thanks in advance (sorry for my english mistakes)